# Wiki & issue-tracking in one system?

Tags: wiki, documentation, issue-tracking

I'm looking for an **integrated solution** that combines **documentation** of a software system with **tracking** of bugs, change requests and feature requests.

*Requirements:*

- Documentation using a wiki would be nice, preferably one supporting CamelCase or other automatic linking.
- Issue tracking must allow a customizable workflow and optional e-mail notifications.

*Known alternatives:*

- [FogBugz](http://www.fogcreek.com/FogBugz/LearnMore.html?section=ScreenshotTool#hist_EnterCases) is an awesome issue tracker, but the [wiki](http://www.fogcreek.com/FogBugz/LearnMore.html?section=ScreenshotTool#hist_RichTextEditor) appears to be somewhat awkward.
- Trac's [wiki](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracWiki) is average (though not as nice as [Foswiki.org](http://Foswiki.org)) but I don't know how good the [integrated issue tracker](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracTickets) is.

**What would you recommend?**  What systems offer the best combination of documentation and issue tracking?

Comment: There's a plugin to Foswiki.org which may be relevant: http://foswiki.org/Extensions/BugsContrib

Comment: Why are you combining the two functions?

Comment: Good question, Iain! Essentially it's KISS: I want few ingedients, few tools, minimal integration effort. A system should be able to easily refer(link) from bugs to wiki pages, and vice versa -- you don't get such integration if you pick two completely separate tools.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We use [Confluence and Jira](http://www.atlassian.com/) for our open source project. It's very reasonably priced and Jira is a top-notch issue tracker.

Comment: This choice seems realistic to us both in terms of features and pricing.

Comment: I've chosen this as the accepted answer because it seems to be a very good option. For other reasons, my place of work is going to use SharePoint instead (it's already installed) and I will see how well we can make that work for us.

Comment: Just to follow up on this a looong time later: As it turns out, Sharepoint is a poor issue tracker and Sharepoint's wiki is bordering on destructive; it's certainly not usable.

Answer (score 4):

The [issue (bug) trackers comparison page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_issue_tracking_systems) at Wikipedia mentions quite a few that integrate with wikis.

- Mantis
- Redmine
- Roundup
- Trac - I have used Trac, but wasn't impressed.
- ikiwiki
- Assembla
- codeBeamer
- Fogbugz - I haven't used Fogbugz, but it was created by Joel Spolsky, who also helped with StackOverflow and Superuser, so it has to be good.

Answer (score 2):

Use Interleave. http://www.interleave.nl/en/ (is open source). You need to do some modeling but the sky is the limit.

Comment: Sounds interesting. Their website looks extremely professional, but lacks actual examples. I get the impression that the cost would be prohibitive.

Answer (score 1):

I know this has been answered already, but for the benefit of future visitors, we use Redmine and it is a very good product.  The issue tracker and wiki work out of the box but are also easy to customize.